# Secure Slim-Rest with Basic Auth

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, slim, basic-authentication

i am new in writing Rest-Apis with PHP. So i use the Slim-Framework for my API.
Now i want to secure the API with HTTP-Basic-AUTH.

My first decision was to do this with htaccess and htpasswd and send the credentials in the Header like

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("test:test")));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

So that work, if i change the User or the Pwd the Server throws an error.

If i search the Web for Securing Slim Rest Api i always find things like Slim/Extras/HttpBasicAuth.php ...
I implemented that but i have problems understanding it.
I also need the .htaccess and htpasswd File , right?

If so, what are the benefits using HttpBasicAuth ?

By jogi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using [Basic Auth Middleware for Slim](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth) you do not need .htaccess nor .htpasswd files. You include the credentials somewhere in your code. Something like:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuth(array(
    "path" => "/api",
    "realm" => "Protected",
    "users" => array(
        "root" => "t00r",
        "user" => "passw0rd"
    )
)));

$app->get("/", function() {
    echo "No password needed.";
});

$app->get("/api", function() {
    echo "API protected by password";
});

$app->run();
```